# Edit and save configuration of a node at runtime without having to stop and then start the flow in Node-RED

Tags: node-red

I have explored Admin APIs which allow you to fetch the flow configuration at runtime. What I wanted to do is edit some node's configuration in a specific flow at runtime without stopping and again stating the flow. I tried to get flows using GET `http://localhost:1880/flows` and made changes in the node in one of the flows and POST it back via https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/post/flows/. It has a deployment option

```
Node-RED-Deployment-Type    full, nodes, flows or reload
```

But when I set it to **nodes**, it behaves the same way as default. This is what I understood to get the desired functionality as it says **- only nodes that have been modified are stopped before the new configuration is applied.** Please let me know if I'm not using it correctly and how to achieve the desired functionality. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I tried.

```
[
{
    "id": "6a88ce89caf39298",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "Flow 2",
    "disabled": false,
    "info": "",
    "env": []
},
{
    "id": "95a1dbdebdb54ffe",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "6a88ce89caf39298",
    "name": "Start",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "6a88ce89caf39298",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "x": 150,
    "y": 100,
    "wires": [
        [
            "c8d27a5901f18ad5"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "c8d27a5901f18ad5",
    "type": "http request",
    "z": "6a88ce89caf39298",
    "name": "",
    "method": "GET",
    "ret": "obj",
    "paytoqs": "ignore",
    "url": "http://localhost:1880/flows",
    "tls": "",
    "persist": false,
    "proxy": "",
    "insecureHTTPParser": false,
    "authType": "",
    "senderr": false,
    "headers": [],
    "x": 370,
    "y": 100,
    "wires": [
        [
            "1e82924352c55a9a"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "1e82924352c55a9a",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "6a88ce89caf39298",
    "name": "function1",
    "func": "var flows = msg.payload;\nvar id = '6a88ce89caf39298';\nmsg.headers = {\n    'Content-Type': 'application/json',\n    'Accept': 'application/json',\n    'Node-RED-Deployment-Type': 'flow'\n};\nfor (var i = 0; i < flows.length; i++) {\n    if (flows[i].z == id && flows[i].id == '1e82924352c55a9a') {\n        flows[i].func = \"return msg\"\n    }\n}\nmsg = {\n    payload: flows\n}\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 600,
    "y": 100,
    "wires": [
        [
            "2224fb1b6f90ce01"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "2224fb1b6f90ce01",
    "type": "http request",
    "z": "6a88ce89caf39298",
    "name": "",
    "method": "POST",
    "ret": "txt",
    "paytoqs": "ignore",
    "url": "http://localhost:1880/flows",
    "tls": "",
    "persist": false,
    "proxy": "",
    "insecureHTTPParser": false,
    "authType": "",
    "senderr": false,
    "headers": [],
    "x": 630,
    "y": 200,
    "wires": [
        [
            "4c8803b9f4e571a5"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "4c8803b9f4e571a5",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "6a88ce89caf39298",
    "name": "debug 2",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 560,
    "y": 280,
    "wires": []
}
  ]
```

Comment: What config node are you updating? All nodes that depend on the config node will also be restarted, this is intentional.